# Extract text between two dots containing a specific word

Tags: python, regex, extract

I'm trying to extract a sentence between two dots. All sentences have inflam or Inflam in them which is my specific word but I don't know how to make that happen.

what I want is  ".The bulk of the underlying fibrous connective tissue consists of diffuse aggregates of chronic inflammatory cells."
or
".The fibrous connective tissue reveals scattered vascular structures and possible chronic inflammation."
from a long paragraph

what I have tried so far is this

```
      #@title Extract microscopic-inflammation { form-width: "20%" }

def inflammation1(microscopic_description):
  
  PATTERNS=[
      
      
    "(?=\.)(.*)(?<=inflamm)",
    "(?=inflamm)(.*)(?<=.)",
       
  
  ]
  
  for pattern in PATTERNS:
        matches = re.findall(pattern, microscopic_description)
        if len(matches) > 0:
            break

  inflammation1 = ''.join([k for k in matches])
  
  return (inflammation1)
         
for index, microscopic_description in enumerate(texts):
    print(inflammation1(microscopic_description)) 
    print("#"*79, index)
```

which hasn't worked for me and it gives me error. when I separate my patterns and run them in different cells they work. The problem is they don't work together to give me the sentence between "." and "." before inflamm and after inflamm.

Comment: You should add the result that you prefer to get with the example. Here is an useful page to test your regex: regex101[dot]com

Comment: What about the first sentence?  that won't have a period preceding it

Comment: the thing is the sentences I am trying to extract are in the middle of 20 different paragraphs. each sentence is unique but they all share "inflam" in them. each sentence starts after a "." and ends with a "."

Comment: The question needs to be clearer. What have you already tried? What problems are you having?

Comment: Please format the code and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I guess this pattern `"\.[^\.]*[iI]nflamm[^\.]*(?=\.)"` may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

string=''  # replace with your paragraph 

print(re.search(r"\.[\s\w]*\.",string).group()) #will print first matched string
print(re.findall(r"\.[\s\w]*\.",string)) #will print all matched strings
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try by checking for the word in every sentence of the text.

```py
for sentence in text.split("."):
    if word in sentence:
        print(sentence[1:])
```

Here you do exactly that and if you find the word, you print the sentence without the space in the start of it. You can modify it in any way you want.